# Jewels and Stones- python error leep code

Tags: python

You're given strings J representing the types of stones that are jewels, and S representing the stones you have.  Each character in S is a type of stone you have.  You want to know how many of the stones you have are also jewels.

The letters in J are guaranteed distinct, and all characters in J and S are letters. Letters are case sensitive, so "a" is considered a different type of stone from "A".

Example 1:

Input: J = "aA", S = "aAAbbbb"
Output: 3

my code:

```
class Solution:
    def numJewelsInStones(self, J: str, S: str) -> int:
        x = 0
        for i in J:
            if J[i] in S:
                x = x+1
        return x
```

The error:

```
Runtime Error
TypeError: string indices must be integers
    if J[i] in S:
Line 5 in numJewelsInStones (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().numJewelsInStones(param_1, param_2)
Line 36 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 47 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

please could someone explain the error and where I have gone wrong as I am quite confused

Comment: `if i in S:` - i is a _letter_ of your string -  not an index - the error tells you exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
class Solution:
    def numJewelsInStones(self, j, s):
        res = [s.count(i) for i in j]
        return sum(res)
```